# Quadratic integer equation depending on an integer

Tags: number-theory, induction

I am trying to prove that for every positive integer $n \ge 3$ there is two odd integers $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $$7a_n^2 + b_n^2 = 2^n.$$

I tried induction, but I was not able to prove it. Is there a way to prove it, and maybe also generalize the problem, for example find all integers $p, q$ such that $$px^2 + y^2=q^n$$ has at least one solution.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with $a_n=1$ and $b_n=2^n-7$ (which is odd for $n\neq 0$)? Do you perhaps mean to have $b_n^2$ rather than $b_n$? And if so, have you considered the case $a_n=b_n$?

Comment: @A.M. it was a typo in my question it is $b_n^2$

Comment: @insipidintegrator in the original question, there was no requirement $7a_n^2<2^n$ as an *integer* can be negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm accustomed to write the $1$ coefficient term first...

if $$   u^2 + 7 v^2  = 2^n   $$
with $u,v$ odd and $u \equiv v \pmod 4,$
then
$$  (u-7v)^2 + 7( u+v)^2  = 2^{n+3}  $$
Both $u+v, u-7v  \equiv 2 \pmod 4.$  Also
$u-7v \equiv u+v \pmod 8 ,$   so their halves are equivalent $\pmod 4.$  Thus
$$ \left( \frac{u-7v}{2} \right)^2 +7 \left( \frac{u+v}{2} \right)^2  = 2^{n+1} $$
in odd numbers   that are congruent $\pmod 4$